# style template for background with radial brush and textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ribbon tab. When one of the tabs is clicked it loads a new page on a grid with some different controls.

I would however like for all grids to have the same background. So I believe this is where Styles are useful & that I can declare one in the app.xaml as part of the application resources.

So I have done this for a row in a datagrid, shown below.

```
 <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="brushRowSend" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

However my background is a radial gradient brush which also has a textblock that contains some text "My App Name".

So currently I have the code below which was mostly created in Blend. So how do I factor this into a style that can be reused rather than copied and pasted?

```
<Grid Grid.RowSpan="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.507,0.504" Opacity="0.75">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1414FD"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0E0D0D" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF2159CF" Offset="0.556"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Direction="200" Color="#FF1212EC"/>
                </Grid.Effect>
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-0.195"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Margin="10,98.593,10,117.706" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFFDF5F5" FontSize="64" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" Width="468.838" FontFamily="Calibri Light">My App Name</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: Is the gradient the only thing you're trying to template? Or the whole thing?

Comment: The whole thing. So the gradient brush & the text block

Comment: You thought about just making it a content control so you can do all that in one line at the instance? Or is there more functionality required of it that it should be like a UserControl of its own or something?

Comment: no its just a background really. Just learning WPF started about two years ago but my day job got in the way so starting again and basically have little knowledge. How do you mean just making it a content control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a VisualBrush. With a VisualBrush you can use any Visual element as a source for painting.

In your case you should do this :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <VisualBrush x:Key="GridBrushKey">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Grid Grid.RowSpan="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.507,0.504" Opacity="0.75">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1414FD"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0E0D0D" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF2159CF" Offset="0.556"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Direction="200" Color="#FF1212EC"/>
                </Grid.Effect>
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-0.195"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Margin="10,98.593,10,117.706" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFFDF5F5" FontSize="64" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" Width="468.838" FontFamily="Calibri Light">My App Name</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource GridBrushKey}">

</Grid>
```